# Slim Framework endpoint unit testing

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I'm trying to write some PHPUnit tests for my small slim framework app, but don't see anywhere  in the docs that point to a way to do a full request and assert on the response (either containing text or a 200 status, or anything, really).

Is there any way to do this that anyone has found/used?

Comment: its been discussed on their help forums within the last 12 months, but its unclear whether it was ever resolved: http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/222-how-to-test-a-silm-app

Answer (score 10):

Here is example how you may test your Slim application:

https://github.com/mac2000/SlimTestable

Suppose we have simple application:

```
<?php
use Slim\Slim;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/', function(){
    echo 'home';
})->name('home');

$app->get('/hello/:name', function($name){
    echo "hello $name";
})->name('hello');

$app->map('/login', function() use($app) {
    if($app->request()->params('login')) {
        $app->flash('success', 'Successfully logged in');
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('hello', array('name' => $app->request()->params('login'))));
    } else {
        $app->flash('error', 'Wrong login');
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));
    }
})->via('GET', 'POST');

$app->run();
```

How do we test it?

Create `App` class:

```
<?php // src/App.php
use Slim\Slim;

class App extends Slim {
    function __construct(array $userSettings = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($userSettings);

        $this->get('/', function(){
            echo 'home';
        })->name('home');

        $this->get('/hello/:name', function($name){
            echo "hello $name";
        })->name('hello');

        $this->map('/login', function() {
            if($this->request()->params('login')) {
                $this->flash('success', 'Successfully logged in');
                $this->redirect($this->urlFor('hello', array('name' => $this->request()->params('login'))));
            } else {
                $this->flash('error', 'Wrong login');
                $this->redirect($this->urlFor('home'));
            }
        })->via('GET', 'POST');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Slim\Http\Response
     */
    public function invoke() {
        $this->middleware[0]->call();
        $this->response()->finalize();
        return $this->response();
    }
}
```

Notice that we move all our routes to new class constructor, also notice new `invoke` method, which do the same as `run` method except it returns response rather than echoing it out.

Now your `index.php` file might be like this one:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App();
$app->run();
```

And now it is time for tests:

```
<?php // tests/ExampleTest.php
use Slim\Environment;

class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $app;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        $this->app = new App();
    }

    public function testHome() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'PATH_INFO' => '/'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertContains('home', $response->getBody());
    }

    public function testHello() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'PATH_INFO' => '/hello/world'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertTrue($response->isOk());
        $this->assertContains('hello world', $response->getBody());
    }

    public function testNotFound() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'PATH_INFO' => '/not-exists'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertTrue($response->isNotFound());
    }

    public function testLogin() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'PATH_INFO' => '/login'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirect());
        $this->assertEquals('Wrong login', $_SESSION['slim.flash']['error']);
        $this->assertEquals('/', $response->headers()->get('Location'));
    }

    public function testPostLogin() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
            'PATH_INFO' => '/login',
            'slim.input' => 'login=world'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirect());
        $this->assertEquals('Successfully logged in', $_SESSION['slim.flash']['success']);
        $this->assertEquals('/hello/world', $response->headers()->get('Location'));
    }

    public function testGetLogin() {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'PATH_INFO' => '/login',
            'QUERY_STRING' => 'login=world'
        ));
        $response = $this->app->invoke();

        $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirect());
        $this->assertEquals('Successfully logged in', $_SESSION['slim.flash']['success']);
        $this->assertEquals('/hello/world', $response->headers()->get('Location'));
    }
}
```

You should notice few things:

While setting up test we are creating `$_SESSION` array for test purposes and instantiate our `App` class object.

In tests rather than `run` we are calling `invoke` which do the same, but returns response object.

`Environment::mock` used to mock requests which are processed with our application.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I was able to rough it and make it work. Here's an example of an endpoint test class.

Assuming you're working in a development environment, you can execute `curl` requests to your own localhost, thus testing before committing to a repo.

First, create your class:

```
class ApiEndpointsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $api_url = "http://localhost/api/v1";

    //create a function that will allow you to call API endpoints at-will.
    private function loadEndpoint($url) {
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return array(
          'body' => $output,
          'info' => $info
        );
    }

    //this allows you to write messages in the test output
    private function printToConsole($statement) {
        fwrite(STDOUT, $statement."\n");
    }
```

Using this, you can write a test function for a particular endpoint response:

```
//this will test the actual body of the response against something expected.
public function testGetUserResponse() {
  $this->printToConsole(__METHOD__);
  $url = $this->api_url."/users/124";
  $response = $this->loadEndpoint($url);
  $expected = '[{"name":"John Smith","email":"john@acme.com"}]';
  $this->assertEquals($response['body'], $expected);
}
```

In a separate test, you can test any other property of the API call's response:

```
public function testGetUserMimeType() {
  $this->printToConsole(__METHOD__);
  $url = $this->api_url."/users/124";
  $response = $this->loadEndpoint($url);
  $this->assertEquals($response['info']['content_type'], 'application/json');
}
```

Your info property options can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

*Side note: if anyone reading this is an expert at PHPUnit and knows a better way, I'm interested in learning about it -- I'm new to PHPUnit.*